# Export table contents from Excel to Word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm really struggling to get a VBA macro to work. Basically, I have a spreadsheet that is used to generate a report. This report is in the form of a Word template, so the code looks for << tag >> and replaces it with a particular value from the spreadsheet.

This all works fine, except for the timeline section. What I want to do is export all of B4[enter image description here][1] and C3 onwards, up to the point where a row is empty. I'm 90% of the way there, but when the table is pasted in to Work, is goes off the page.

Is there any way to fix this so the pasted area fits on the page? Here is my code:

```
' ** Populate Incident Timeline **
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("B4:C" & LastRow).Select
Selection.Copy
.Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<< timeline >>"
.Application.Selection.Find.Execute
.Application.Selection.PasteSpecial
```

Here is an example screenshot of the table once it's pasted from the macro:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPLEH.png

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Researching this for hours, and sods law I find the answer right after posting. This fixed the issue for me:

```
    '** Populate Incident Timeline **
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("B4:C" & LastRow).Select
Selection.Copy
.Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<< timeline >>"
.Application.Selection.Find.Execute
.Application.Selection.PasteExcelTable False, True, False
```